# JavaScript - Adding permissions on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm reading [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2)

Until now, I used the sample code in the link above under "Quick start" section. And basically, what I got is a log in button, and when I click on it, a window appears saying that the application is going to use my public profile and email.

I want to expand the permissions, for example getting an access to the likes/friends etc...

According to the tutorial, I need to add the following code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
 }, {scope: 'user_friends'});
```

However I don't understand where should I add it in the code that under the quick start section in the tutorial.

Where should I add it?

Thanks

Comment: Allow to use public profile and email by clicking "OK", Facebook will again ask for user_friends permission in next dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial they use component "fb:login-button" so that's where you specify scopes

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

or you can use your own button with onclick event

```
function buttonOnClickHandler (){

    FB.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
        // specify desired scopes here
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'});

}
```